# Getting mobile number from log to the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-telephony

My app deals with phone calls.I want to send an auto textmessage(sms) to the dialer when the line is busy or else user is busy or else call is in hold....Here I want to get the mobile no of the dialer to my app..Is it possible????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not posible. You can't interact with the dialer on iOS.

Comment: Thanks......Whether it is possible to activate my app when the call is in progress???

Comment: No and yes, the user can start your app while on a call but you can't start an app programmatically when a call is in progress.

Comment: Is it possible to find the carrier Id of the new caller (callers contacts not in address book).....

Comment: No, CoreTelephony will lett you know if there is an active call and its state thats is: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603